# How to apply css using ng-class in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, node.js, indexing

I have a tag in which I want to apply class when I have no data in my field.

```
<label class="col-xs-6 btn btn-white" ng-click="checkMultiSelect(vm.settingsObj.customfields_student,val.key)" ng-class="{'active': vm.settings.customfields_student.indexOf(????) == -1 }">
```

My settings object is like this:

```
"details": {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "58413d990533de0d1a3a4986",
    "customfields_student": [
      ""
    ],
  }
}
```

Can any one suggest help for me on how I can apply class when it is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the code:

You need to check the `length` of your array.

```
 ng-class="{'active': vm.settings.customfields_student.length==0 }"
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12841/).

Comment: Thanks for your help but how to activate the class when i have no "customfields_student" in db i.e details={};

Comment: Please use this: `ng-class="{'active': details.customfields_student==undefined }"`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property, It returns the number of elements in an array.

```
ng-class="{'active': vm.settings.customfields_student.length == 0 || vm.settings.customfields_student[0].length == 0 }"
```

If can use `String.length` property to check the length of first element.